# JavaScript Canvas -- Is it possible to draw depending upon Math.random?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a very basic sprite for a game (it is drawn in Canvas/Context/LineTo). I want its expression to change randomly based on two different draw methods. This is my attempt at this:

```
            drawFace = function () {
                if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
                    Player.drawhappyface(context);
                }
                else if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
                    Player.drawsadface(context);
                }
            }

            drawFace();
```

I can confirm that the drawhappyface and drawsadface draw methods work independent of this function (respectively drawing a smile and a frown). But using this function and its logic, they're simply never drawn (the player entirely lacks a face). So, have I written this wrong? I'm inspired by the following simulation which has constantly animating expressions also using Math.random: http://www.blobsallad.se/

If I instead write the function like this, then absolutely nothing is drawn on the canvas (all other sprites, etc. also not drawn):

```
        drawFace = function (context) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
                Player.drawhappyface(context);
            }
            else if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
                Player.drawsadface(context);
            }
        }

        drawFace();
```

Comment: You have an `if...else if...` with low probabilities and no `else`, of course there will be several instances where it does nothing.

Comment: Your second `drawFace` expects an argument called `context`, but when you call it, you supply zero arguments. i.e., you do `drawFace()` instead of `drawFace(foo)`. Why tell `drawFace` to expect an argument if you don't supply one when you call it? As a result`context` is `undefined` inside the function

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you call `Math.random()` in both `if` statements and then they will have different values. Call `Math.random()` only once and save the value for every time you need/call `drawFace` Try like so:

```js
drawFace = function () {
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    console.log(randomNumber);
    if (randomNumber < 0.05) {
        console.log('randomNumber < 0.05');
    }
    else if (randomNumber < 0.1) {
        console.log('randomNumber < 0.1');
    }
}

drawFace();
```

if you just want to draw happy or sad face you can do even simpler `if else`

```js
drawFace = function () {
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    console.log(randomNumber);
    if (randomNumber < 0.5) {
        console.log('draw happy face');
    } else {
        console.log('draw sad face');
    }
}

drawFace();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. This worked! No idea why you're downvoted! I have noticed that my character's happy and sad faces now randomly draw! Thank you! However, there is a noticeable gap where nothing is drawn, unlike my inspiration (http://www.blobsallad.se/), so I will have to work on the math/think of a workaround.

Comment: @spaceships111 see now it will also log the `randomNumber` every time you click on "Run code snippet" you might need to change your if else depending on what ever you want.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you further, but my happyface and sadface expressions change rapidly constantly changing, and thus looks very bad. This is very unlike the following where it changes smoothly every ~second: http://www.blobsallad.se/ which is strange to me as I'm using the same math for the randomNumber. I might have to make a follow up question expanding upon this.

Comment: @spaceships111 sorry haven't seen this until now. I don't understand your last comment, what do you get, why you get it and what you are trying to achieve..